# Create Composite GroupBy Expression at runtime

Tags: c#, linq

Following code helps me create a `GroupBy` with one property at runtime, by supplying the property name, but I am not able to create a composite `GroupBy`, where it can be done on multiple properties of a Type, any suggestion / pointer:

// Linqpad Code

```
void Main()
{
    ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "o");

    IQueryable queryableRecords = Product.FetchQueryableProducts();

    Expression expression = queryableRecords.GroupBy("Name");

    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Product>>>>(expression)
                         .Compile();

    func().Dump();
}

public static class ExpressionTreesExtension
{
    public static Expression GroupBy(this IQueryable queryable, string propertyName)
    {
        var propInfo = queryable.ElementType.GetProperty(propertyName);

        var collectionType = queryable.ElementType;

        var groupParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collectionType, "g");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(groupParameterExpression, propInfo);
        var groupLambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, groupParameterExpression);
        return Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
                               "GroupBy", 
                               new Type[] { collectionType, propInfo.PropertyType }, 
                               queryable.Expression, 
                               Expression.Quote(groupLambda));

    }
}



public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static IQueryable<Product> FetchQueryableProducts()
        {
            List<Product> productList = new List<Product>()
            {
              new Product {Id=1, Name = "A"},
              new Product {Id=1, Name = "B"},
              new Product {Id=1, Name = "A"},
              new Product {Id=2, Name = "C"},
              new Product {Id=2, Name = "B"},
              new Product {Id=2, Name = "C"},
            };

            return productList.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use an anonomous groupby GroupBy(x => new { a = m, b = n, c = o})

Comment: @jdweng Creating an anonymous type at runtime is a problem in itself :-) (in truth you create a type)

Comment: @mrinal You'll probably lose less nights by using a Dynamic Linq library prepackaged :-) Look for them on nuget... there should be at least two or three.

Comment: @jdweng I tried that but not much success, in creating the correct anonymous type, was thinking if GroupBy can be integrated via Expression trees itself

Comment: @xanatos aware of them, but doing it to learn, for the self

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The concept of "learning" isn't based on the "make this for me", it is based on "I go on github and take a look at how others did it.". The "original" Dynamic Linq is less than 2500 lines, in a single file, [source available](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic/DynamicLinq.cs). One is free to reinvent the wheel, but he isn't free to ask others to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks @xanatos, let me check, if I can use that to understand better, have tried multiple ways to weave `GroupBy` but failed miserably till now > 1 property

Comment: Suppose you was able to do that. Now the resulting lambda will be of type `IGrouping<SomeType, Product>`, where `SomeType` is some type which have all properties you grouped by. So you should not really create that type at runtime but use some predefined type with known properties, to be able to work with resulting lambda.